# sfDoctrineGuard not respecting backend controller

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

As most symfonians, I have a backend (be) controller where admins can login to administer apps for a site. The problem I am having is the login form is not respecting the backend (be) controller. For example:

```
<form action="/guard/login" method="post">
```

Should be:

```
<form action="be.php/guard/login" method="post">
```

So everytime I submit the form it keeps throwing an error. The weird thing is, it works for be_dev.php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the `no_script_name` setting in your backend? The plugin [uses the standard `url_for` helper](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/_signin_form.php#L3) to generate the link, so if all other links work on your backend, this should do as well.

You can find the `no_script_name` config parameter in your application's settings.yml file.

Comment: Set to true for production, and false for test and dev.

Comment: @Digital Precision: that depends - is it his primary front controller?

Comment: No, the primary front controller is 'fe', the secondary is 'be'.

Comment: In that case, set `no_script_name` to `false` for all environments. Your default front controller is `fe`, that means every request without a filename will be redirected there (to index.php) - so your login url in the question logs in to the frontend, not the backend.